# Unable to use JUnit 5 automatic extension registration

Tags: junit5

I'd like to use [automatic extension registration](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic), but for some reason the extension does not kick in. If I register it declarativelly: `@ExtendWith(SomeExtension.class)` it works. So extension tiself is not the problem.

If I try to verify if ServiceLoader part is correct:

```
ServiceLoader<Extension> load = ServiceLoader.load(Extension.class);
List<Extension> extensions = StreamSupport.stream(
    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(load.iterator(), 0), false).toList();
```

I can see my extension, so it's not the ServiceLoader part either. If I try to verify, whether the configuration was correctly applied, and do:

```
@Value("${junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled}")
private String enabled;
```

it has value

```
"true"
```

so it's not properties/configuration problem either. Yet the extension is not kicking in. Its constructor isn't even reached (with `@ExtendWith` it does). And if I look into build output directory, the ServiceLoader config and extension .class are both there where they should be, so it's not packaging issue either. And if I invalidate/reimport/... intellij idea IDE project data, it also does not help, so it's not intellij idea incorrectly constructed classpath either (but that would show earlier as it would block ServiceLoader to work correctly)

Can someone suggest what can cause that? I'm running out of ideas.

UPDATE: I'd expect the ServiceLoader stuff being handled by ServiceLoader call. I looked into every junit jar I know, and I didn't find it anywhere. Does anyone at least know which part of JUnit(which jar) should handle this logic?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with enabling `ServiceLoader` feature. The code invoking the `ServiceLoader` is here: `MutableExtensionRegistry`, and putting junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled into `application.properties` is incorrect, as JUnit expect it in: `junit-platform.properties`, or elsewhere  as explained in [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params).